# error while running grails command line

Tags: grails

in my grails 2.3.4 application (after upgrading from grails 2.2.3) , when I run the grails command line `grails install-plugin pluginname` I get the below  error , even I tried `grails list-plugins` I'm getting the same error:

```
    Error Resolve error obtaining dependencies: Failed to resolve dependencies (Se log level to 'warn' in BuildConfig.groovy for more information): org.grails.plugins:tomcat:2.3.4 (Use --stacktrace to see the full trace)
```

i reviewed the BuildConfig.groovy there is no tomcat 2.3.4 what i'm using is 7.0.47 , here are my plugins :

```
runtime ":hibernate:3.6.10.6"
runtime ":jquery:1.8.3"
runtime  :resources:1.1.6
build ":tomcat:7.0.47"
runtime database-migration:1.2.1
compile :cache:1.0.1
```

how i can solve this issue ?

Comment: Could you set the log level to 'warn' and use the --stacktrack like the error suggests? That will be more verbose and indicate specifically which dependencies are not getting resolved. Also, if you are setting your dependencies in BuildConfig, there is no need to be running install-plugin on the command line.

Comment: Clean your project in `.grails`. Issue a `grails clean` and move ahead. Also note, `grails install-plugin` is no more used in Grails 2.3.*. Plugins has to be manually installed in `BuildConfig`. As a side note, also check `application.properties` is not referring to any plugin.

Comment: Please make sure your plugins in BuildConfig are surrounded by quotes and begin with a colon. For example, you have `runtime database-migration:1.2.1` when it should be `runtime ":database-migration:1.2.1"`

Comment: @dmahapatro even with grails clean , i'm getting the above error

Comment: @grantmc does it make any difference if i wrote single or double quotes ?

Comment: Nope. Single or double quotes will work. It just needs to be a String.

Answer (score 0):

you problem seems slovable due to the fact that ...you need to clean the grails project first without building it and then do

```
grails refresh-dependencies
```

and then finally

```
grails clean
```

and

```
grails compile
```

When you run `refresh-dependencies` your Grails application will try to resolve your grails plugins defined in `BuildConfig.groovy` file. If this doesn't work remove the plugins and do the above step until the error you have posted in the question vanished then add the correct plugin format and version with the correct precedence dependency, then make sure everything should work well.

Answer (score 0):

Your dependencies are in a dependency block, but they are plugins. Put them in the plugins block of your `BuildConfig.groovy` file. So instead of what you have, put this:

```
plugins {    
    runtime ":hibernate:3.6.10.6"
    runtime ":jquery:1.8.3"
    runtime ":resources:1.1.6"
    build   ":tomcat:7.0.47"
    runtime ":database-migration:1.2.1"
    compile ":cache:1.0.1"
}
```

Also, this is no "dependency" block. This is a dependencies block, however. See [this link](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/conf.html#dependencyResolution) for information on dependency resolution in Grails.

Answer (score 0):

I need to add the following repo in buildconfig.groovy to the repositories section:

```
mavenRepo "https://repo.grails.org/grails/plugins"
```